# C# Calculation current half year

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

I would like to calculate the last half-year starting from the today in c#.

A first half-year in my scenario is  01/01/ - 06/30/.
A second half-year in my scenario is 07/01/ - 12/31/.

How would you calculate this using DateTime?

Example: Today is 03/15/2014 -> last half-year: 07/01/2013 - 12/31/2013

Example: Today is 07/15/2014 -> last half-year: 01/01/2014 - 06/30/2014.

Thanks in advance! ;-)

Comment: Compare with `now >= new DateTime(now.Year, 7, 1)`

Comment: That should be an answer

Comment: Why is the  last half-year 2013 even if the current year is 2014?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It sounds like the OP wants the completed half-year. So your answer should be correct if you use `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6)`, like GvS's updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to look at the month from 6 months ago, and determine the half it is in:

```
DateTime start, end;

var date = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);
var month = date.Month;
var year = date.Year;
if (month <= 6) {
    start = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    end = new DateTime(year, 6, 30);
} else {
    start = new DateTime(year, 7, 1);
    end = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't evaluate `DateTime.Today` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just have an if else where you check if month is greater than 6 and create date range as below.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if(today.Month > 6)
    Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(today.Year,1,1).ToShortDateString() + "->" + 
                      new DateTime(today.Year,6,30).ToShortDateString());
else
    Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(today.Year-1,6,1).ToShortDateString() + "->" + 
                      new DateTime(today.Year-1,12,31).ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var start = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Today.Year,
    1 + 6 * (DateTime.Today.Month / 7),
    1);
var end = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Today.Year + DateTime.Today.Month / 7,
    7 - 6 * (DateTime.Today.Month / 7),
    1).AddDays(-1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step back by one day until you hit either Month 12 or Month 06

```
// get first of this month
DateTime prev =  new DAteTime( DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);

bool found = false;
while(found == false){
    prev = prev.AddDays(-1);
    if(prev.Month == 12)
        found = true;
    if(prev.Month == 6)
        found = true
} 

// then when found, count back 6 months from that

DateTime start = prev.AddMonths(-6)

// then get the first of that month
start = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, 1);
```

Comment: My brain is still fuzzy this morning. GvS's answer is way simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below snippet.

```
            string firstHalf = "30/06/";

            int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Date.Year;

            if (DateTime.Now.Date > Convert.ToDateTime(firstHalf + Convert.ToString(currentYear)).Date)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Last Half Year : " + "01/01/" + Convert.ToString(currentYear) + " to  30/06/" + Convert.ToString(currentYear));
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Last Half Year : " + "01/07/" + Convert.ToString(currentYear - 1) + " to  31/12/" + Convert.ToString(currentYear - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys. I prefer the answer of GvS.

I was doing this:

```
            var halfyear = (float)DateTime.Today.Month / 6;
            var halfyearModulo = halfyear % 1;

            if (halfyearModulo == 0)
                halfyear--;

            var minimumDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, ((int)halfyear * 6) + 1, 1).AddMonths(-6);
            var maximumDate = minimumDate.AddMonths(6);
```

But i think GvSs anwser is way better.